# How to not repeat the same code and use components or functions in react instead?

Tags: reactjs

i have a component within which i want to display the card that accepts the list and another card next to it that displays ImageComponent if state.complete. if not displays the status text.

As you see from code below,

```
render() {

    return (
        <OuterComponent>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="card">
                    <form onSubmit={this.on_submit}>
                        <div className="top_content">
                            <div className="title">title</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="content">
                            <label>
                                <div>
                                    <SvgOne />
                                    Plus button
                                </div>
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    onChange={this.handle_files}
                                    multiple />
                            </label>

                            <ul className="files_list">
                                {this.state.files.map((f, index) => (
                                    <li key={f.name}>
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="bottom_content">
                            <button type="submit">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>


                {(this.state.loading || this.props.list_id) &&
                    <div>
                        {this.state.complete
                            ? <Fragment>
                                <div className="content">
                                    <ChildComponentOne/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="bottom_content">
                                    <div className="title">title</div>
                                </div>
                            </Fragment>

                            : <Fragment>
                                <div className="content">
                                    {this.state.failed &&
                                        <div>
                                            <SvgRetry/>
                                        </div>}
                                    <div className="cancel_button">
                                        <SvgClose/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={status_classes.join(' ')}>
                                        {this.get_text}...
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="bottom_content">
                                    {list && list.listname
                                        ? <div className="title">title</div>
                                        : <div/>}
                                </div>
                            </Fragment>
                        }
                    </div>
            </div>
        </OuterComponent>
    );
}
```

I have used the div with classname "content" repeatedly. It contains ImageComponent if the state.complete  if not displays some other content with in. I have duplicated the code. But i wanted it to be a seperate component such that it could be used elsewhere.

What could be the best approach in this case. Could someone provide some insight into this. thanks.

Comment: Just because of the uses the same CSS class, does not necessarily mean it should be a reusable component. It totally depends on your code, how many more places you want to use the same logic if it is here only duplicating is the best solution, for maintaining and lower complexity. 
If you really insist on making a component out of what is wrapped by `<div className="content">`, you should architectect it properly, what should be passed as props. This code  does not make it clear what exactly should be developed

Comment: you can define a subfunction returnig parts you need and call it in jsx by `{commonContent()}`